# gam/gamm when response variable is complex

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gamm4, complex-numbers

I would like to fit a generalized additive mixed model using mgcv or gamm4, but have a response variable consisting of complex numbers where y=a+1i*b. Is this possible, and if so are there any special procedures I need to implement in order to properly fit/work with such a model?